# Вечер может быть "особенно оживлён"?

Tags: выбор-слов

> После столь экстравагантного приглашения к алтарю все последующие
>   вечеринки в общих компаниях заканчивались скандалом.
>   Прелестный вечер не предвещал обычно ничего такого, напротив – был
>   особенно оживлён. Но в какой-то момент градус чувств-с в гостиных повышался, и я непременно оказывалась в чём-то виновной.

Оживлённость вечера как противовес скандалу?

Предложите, пожалуйста, что-нибудь... красивое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре Ефремовой:
**оживлённый**, *прил.*
2) а) исполненный движения, суеты, деятельности; шумный.

Эдуард Леон Кортес. «Оживленный вечер перед Парижской оперой» (картина)

*Оживленный вечер тихо завершился возле большого камина в библиотеке* (Урсула Ле Гуин).
*Однако надежда на оживленный вечер не оправдывалась* (Б. Федоров).
*Как необычайно красив и оживлён вечер в курортном городе!* (В. Туловский)
*Только под конец выдался один особенно оживлённый вечер* (Э. В. Экк).

Мне кажется, что возможно оставить как есть, потому что *в момент повышения градусов чувств-с* появляется напряженность, оживление сменяется смущенным молчанием, возникает желание исчезнуть. И только потом уже "вовсю горит скандал".

Можно использовать другие определения: **жизнерадостный** (в противовес состоянию в скандале — жить не хочется!) или **беззаботный** (скандал — это проблема).

Прелестный вечер не предвещал обычно ничего такого, напротив – был оживлённым и совершенно беззаботным (или оживленно-беззаботным).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написала так:

После столь экстравагантного приглашения к алтарю все последующие вечеринки в общих компаниях заканчивались скандалом. Обычно **прелестный** вечер не предвещал  ничего такого, **а  напротив – казался   радушным и приятно оживленным.** Но в какой-то момент градус чувств-с в гостиных повышался, и я непременно оказывалась в чём-то виновной.

Пояснение

1) Событие повторяющееся, поэтому глагол ***был*** не совсем подходит.

2) Нужно подчеркнуть переход от **добродушного** оживления к последующему выяснению отношений.

3) Вечеринка — вечер (повтор?). Определение не кажется очень удачным (милый, изысканный, восхитительный, очаровательный, очаровательно-изысканный и т.д.).